# Numerous dead links in the community FAQ

Tags: bug, status-completed, faq-update-request

There are numerous dead links in the [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

**Formatting and editing**

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22192

**Reputation, badges and voting**

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6853

**Accounts, registration and login**

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4219

**Other**

https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5399

In addition, the last link in the FAQ pointing to the migration is dead as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That post is Community Wiki, so you always have the option of editing it yourself. I've gone ahead and removed those links now, though, since the questions were deleted a few weeks ago.

Some of the information in the [now-deleted FAQ migration question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/how-can-the-stack-overflow-faqs-be-improved-as-they-are-transferred-to-meta) might be useful for indicating how future FAQ posts should be written, so I'll sift through it later and see if any of it's worth copying somewhere else (or if it's already adequately covered elsewhere).

Comment: I pondered editing the wiki myself however I feel a little awkward editing something that important.  Thanks anyway :)